# writing a time out event for android

Tags: java, android

i have a small issue i can't figure out.
for my program, i basically want to execute some code if the user hasn't done anything with the application for 5 minutes (say log out).

how can i go about doing this? i'm lost on detecting that the user has done nothing, and then reset the count once the user has touched the tablet or something.  can somebody give me some pointers?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

So if you are having single Activity in your app then you create a Timer and TimerTask to achieve this. And can track touch and key events.So in your activity you can do something like this.

```
Timer longTimer;
synchronized void setupLongTimeout(long timeout) {
  if(longTimer != null) {
    longTimer.cancel();
    longTimer = null;
  }
  if(longTimer == null) {
    Timer longTimer = new Timer();
    longTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        longTimer.cancel();
        longTimer = null;
        //do your stuff, i.e. finishing activity etc.
      }
    }, 300000 /*delay in milliseconds i.e. 5 min = 300000 ms or use timeout argument*/);
  }
}
@override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
  setupLongTimeout(300000);
  return super.onTouchEvent(me);
}
@override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent ke) {
  setupLongTimeout(300000);
  return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, ke);
}
```

If you are handling any key/touch events for any of the views then you need to return false so that event comes to the activity.

Comment: hm interesting, i'll give this a shot. looks awesome though, thanks

Comment: really be careful how you implement the onTouchEvent, if you have other objects in your layout, you have to make sure you reset the timer.

Comment: @bhups I want to implement this logic in my App, but I have multiple activities. Can u pls suggest a simple to incorporate this across multiple activities ?

Comment: Instead of overriding `onTouchEvent` and `onKeyUp`, use the callback for `onUserInteraction` on your activity. This will trigger for all objects on your activity. If you want to do this in multiple activities, I suggest you write an activity class that extends `Activity` and then have all your activities extend that.