# Automatic Logout feature in Android App

Tags: android, logout, session-timeout

I am building a native android app, where I want the user to be automatically logged out (kind of session timeout) after a period of inactivity say 5 mins.

It is a standalone app and there are multiple screens in the App. I am not maintaining any user session with a server.

**P.S**: I found a possible solution in [writing a time out event for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615187/writing-a-time-out-event-for-android). But that is suitable only for a single Activity application. Can anyone suggest a similar solution for a multi-activity app ?

Comment: More details would help people to answer this.. what are they logging in to? Are there network requests involved? A simple solution could be to simply store a timestamp somewhere that you check for expiry, you could write the timestamp in onPause, and check it in onResume and it would be accessible to your entire app.

Comment: @Theblacknight I'm calling a REST web service to authenticate the user during login. Apart from that there are more web service calls in various screens to retrieve/store certain information. However, this is standalone application & I am not maintaining any user session.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in response to the link you posted, why not follow that approach but create some sort of abstract base activity, that all of your other activities extend. So essentially you are adding a timeout to each activity, but your base activity will handle this, your child activities will not need to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LogoutService extends Service {
    public static CountDownTimer timer;
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
      timer = new CountDownTimer(1 *60 * 1000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               //Some code
                Log.v(Constants.TAG, "Service Started");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Log.v(Constants.TAG, "Call Logout by Service");
                // Code for Logout
                stopSelf();
            }
         };
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
 }
 }
And then Add the below code in every activity.

@Override
 protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onResume();

LogoutService.timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStop();
LogoutService.timer.cancel();
}
```