# Custom timeout for method

Tags: android, android-facebook

How do I put a custom timeout for a method?
I need to put a custom timeout on connecting to facebook, but when the connection is too slow, the app hangs. Any suggestion on what I need to add so that it will notify the user after a minute?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html). Start a new Timer and make it wait for your timeout length. If your request completes successfully, then cancel the timer. Otherwise use the Timer to cancel the request and notify the user.

> but when the connection is too slow, the app hangs

I hope you're not doing networking on the main thread!

Comment: Ok i'll try that. I'm logging into facebook, getting active session and getting user profile. Oh wait.. should that be in an AsyncTask?

Comment: Can you give me sample code on how to use timertask as a timeout? I can only see sample code that delays the method.

Comment: Why don't you upload some code? AsyncTask sounds like a good fit for what you're doing. Instead of timing out you can keep the user updated using the onProgressUpdate(). And if the user gets fed up because of their network, you can allow them to cancel the request of their own accord.

Comment: Using the Timer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615187/writing-a-time-out-event-for-android